# Class of matrices such that every element of their kernel contains a zero coordinate

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

Consider the following class of matrices:

$$S=\{A\in M_n(\mathbb{R}): Ax=0\Rightarrow \exists i: x_i =0\}$$

I have two questions:

1. Is this set known by any name?
2. What are some equivalent ways of characterizing this behavior for a given $A$? E.g. would it be correct to state that $A\in S$ if and only if $A$ has a column $a_i$ which is not contained in the linear span of its remaining columns: $\exists i: a_i \not \in \langle a_j\rangle_{j\neq i}$?

Comment: 1. No, there is no name for that. 2. You can say that there is at least one column that is orthogonal to all the others.

Comment: No, it is only a sufficient condition. See below.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan what is your above comment "No..." in response to?

Comment: @gen I wrote "No..." in response to KBS' answer 2.

Answer (score 1):

The set $S$ has not been well-defined (what is $x$?). Do you mean
$$S = \{A \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R}) : \forall x \in \mathrm{Ker}(A), ~\exists i \in [1,n], ~x_i=0\} ?$$
If yes, the set $S$ is large since it contains all invertible matrices.

Moreover, $S = S_1 \cup \ldots \cup S_n$, where $S_i$ denotes the set of all matrices whose kernel is entirely contained
in the hyperplane $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : x_i=0\}$.

Indeed, if no such hyperplane contains $\mathrm{Ker}(A)$, then for each $i$ one can find a vector in $\mathrm{Ker}(A)$ whose $i$-th coordinate is not zero. By taking suitable linear combinations of such vectors, we get a vector in $\mathrm{Ker}(A)$ without any null coordinate.

Last, $S_i$ is exactly the set of all matrices $A \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ whose $i$-th column is not a linear combination of the other ones, so your guess is correct. Indeed, saying that the $i$-th column is a linear combination of the other ones is equivalent to say that $\mathrm{Ker}(A)$ contains some vector whose $i$-th coordinate is $1$ (equivalently, is not $0$).

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I should have mentioned, but I am aware of this way of looking at it. I am looking for some additional characterizations.

Comment: I have just completed my answer to prove that your guess is true.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate definition are matrices that consist of columns for which some of them are orthogonal to all the others.

Consider $x$ such that $Ax=\sum_i x_ia_i=0$ and assume that the first column is orthogonal to all the others. Then, we have that $a_1^TAx=||a_1||^2_2x_1=0$, which implies that we necessarily have $x_1=0$.

The general case follows from the same arguments repeated multiple times.

Comment: You prove only a sufficient condition, which can be relaxed by considering any scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and not only the canonical one. Then, the condition « there exists some scalar product for which some column of $A$ is orthogonal to the other ones » is equivalent to the condition « some column of $A$ is not contained in the linear span of the other ones ». But your argument do not prove that this relaxed condition is necessary.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have updated the answer and will get back to it it when I find some time.